# Changing the height and design of the tab bar below an ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

i am designing an app, ios based. i am doing this with the guidelines of apple. but i have a question about the tab bar below the app. Apps like spotify, facebook ,whatsapp and twitter are using a tab bar below the screen.

Is it possible in de 'code' to change the height of this? I am asking this because of the target audience. also the font-size.

**Example**
https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/facebook-updated-screenshot-ios-7.png?w=730&crop=1

sorry if the question does not belong here in the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the height of an UITabBar or the font size of the bar button labels.
If you need this, you must either build your own TabBar or see if someone has already done it. (Search for UITabBar or UITabBarController replacement)

Comment: thank you for your comment, so if i design my own then it is possible? but the original of apple is not possible to change